# How to compare specific elements of a nested list, when the nested list is the value of a dictionary?

Tags: python

Using Python, I'm trying to compare specific elements of lists within two nested lists such that the element closest in value to the second element is printed. These nested lists are the values of keys in a dictionary. Its probably easier to visualize

```
myFstDict = {key1 : list1,         mySecDict = {key2 : list2,
             key1A: list1A}                     key2A: list2A}

list 1 = [ [a, 10, b],            list 2 = [ [g, 41, h],
           [c, 22, d],                       [i, 50, j],
           [e, 43, f], ]                     [k, 73, l], ]
```

In this case I'm taking the second element of the first element in list 2 (which is 41) and finding which second element of the lists in list 1 is closest in value. So I'm comparing 41 with 10, 22, and 43. The answer would be 43 since it is closest in value to 41. I would then need to print the index of that list containing 43. This would then be repeated for the next element of list 2 (which is [i, 50, j]). I only included one list from each dictionary for simplicity sake.

the code I have so far to accomplish this is as follows:

```
for key in myDict:
for i in range(len(mySecDict[key])):
    elmt_of_intrst = mySecDict[key][i][1]
    x=0
    while ((int(elmt_of_intrst) - int(myFirstDict[key][x][1])) > 0):
        x = x+1
    index_of_list = x
```

I understand this is a flawed code because the **elements are not always in increasing order like shown**. I've just been banging my head against the wall trying to find a better way to do this for a few days now so any guidance would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you in advance and please let me know if I did not follow any protocol correctly. This is my first time asking a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `abs()` function to get difference betweeen two elements. Followed by the `min` part of `min-max` algo.

```
for key in myDict:
 for k in mySecDict[key]:
    elmt_of_intrst = k[1]
    ind=0 
    val=abs(int(elmt_of_intrst) - int(myFirstDict[key][0][1]))
    for i in myFirstDict[key]: #every row in 2d list
     temp_val=i[1] # value at 2nd position/1st index
     difference = abs(int(elmt_of_intrst) - int(temp_val))
     if (difference < val):

        val = difference
        ind = [myFirstDict[key].index(i),i.index(temp_val)]
    print ind
```

**`min` algorithm** :

1. initialize val with the difference from first element of array & initialize ind with 0th index.
2. Loop for all elements in the array :

   - if next value(absolute difference between two elements) is less than `val` update `val` and update `ind` to its location